# Show total number of points in Grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana

I store time period of a certain operation in Graphite. In my Grafana dashboard I show all the points which are greater than 15 minutes. I also want to show the count of such incidents daily. Is it possible to do so in Graphite/Grafana without adding a new metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only show points that have a value > 15 minutes ( 15 min = 900,000ms )

```
removeBelowValue(test.a.b.c, 900000)
```

To get a running count of hits from the above:

```
A: removeBelowValue(test.a.b.c, 900000)
B: integral(divideSeries(removeBelowValue(test.a.b.c, 900000), #A))
```

Once you have both series queries entered, you can click the eyeball next to the `A` series to hide it, as the value we care about is going to come from `B`.

The value of this series will be the number of instances the `A` query has been above 900000.